# Looking for Ibn Ezra Riddle

Tags: sources-mekorot, fast-days, avraham-ibn-ezra

I'm looking for the Hebrew of an Ibn Ezra riddle related to fast days: "the short, the long, the black, the white, the man, the woman."
Does anyone have a source, or the Hebrew for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider providing where you saw (or heard) this riddle attributed to Ibn Ezra.

Comment: I haven't looked through these, but maybe start here? https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%97%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%91%22%D7%A2

Comment: I don't know where I heard this, probably from a teacher eons ago.

Comment: If it wasn't attributed to the Ibn Ezra initially, now it will be

Answer (score 7):

I found the riddle written [here](http://app.shaanan.ac.il/pic/games/new/ktav-hida-zomot.pdf), [here](https://teman.org.il/content/9937) and [here](https://m.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=2340617969534923&id=1499357956994266&locale2=ar_AR) (and mentioned in a couple of other places where it seems to have been written by memory and may not necessarily be the correct order of the riddle), but none of them say that it's from the Ibn Ezra. The Hebrew is thus:

> הארוך
>
> הקצר
>
> השחור
>
> הלבן
>
> הוא
>
> היא

Translated, it's:
"The long, the short, the black, the white, him, her."

or:

> "מהו ארוך וקצר, שחור ולבן, הוא והיא?"

Translated: "What is long and short, black and white, him and her?"

And the solution in the same order: 17th of Tammuz, 10th of Tevet, 9th of Av, Yom Kippur, Tzom Gedaliah, Ta'anit Ester.